# visual studio not recognizing public constructor, function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010.

C# File1:

```
 namespace Level1.Level2
    {
        public class MyObject
        {

            public int _Number = 0;
            public MyObject(int number)
            {
                _Number = number;
            }
            public System.Messaging.MessageQueue FunctionA() 
            {
                  ///
          }
     }
```

C# File 2:

```
using Level1.Level2;
namespace AnotherNS
{
   public mainfunction()
   {
      MyObject myoj1 = new MyObject(1);
      System.Messaging.MessageQueue SomeQueue = Level1.Level2.MyObject.FunctionA();
      myoj1 .FunctionA(SomeQueue );
   }
 }
```

This gives me error saying

> Level1.Level2.MyObject doesnt contain a constructor that takes 1
>   arguement error2: Level1.Level2.MyObject doesnt contain a definition
>   for the functions error3: its saying Level1.Level2.MyObject is
>   inaccessible due to its protection level

The Object was Protected, but I changed it to public, so do the functions. MyObject is not inherited from any thing.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You will at least need to change this line: `System.Messaging.MessageQueue SomeQueue = myObj1.FunctionA();`

Comment: Are you sure you can compile the first assembly containing MyObject? FunctionA is missing a closing }.

Comment: Chris is correct. That line implies that class/method are static.

Comment: The second code snippet isn't valid.  That function must be inside a class.  As written, its directly inside a namespace.

Comment: This is **all** just wrong.

Answer (score 4):

See comments in code:

```
namespace Level1.Level2
{
    public class MyObject
    {

        public int _Number = 0;
        public MyObject(int number)
        {
            _Number = number;
        }
        public System.Messaging.MessageQueue FunctionA() 
        {
            ///////
        //missing brace
        }
      }
 }
```

---

```
using Level1.Level2;
namespace AnotherNS
{
   //missing class!
   public class MyClass
   {
     public mainfunction()
     {
       MyObject myoj1 = new MyObject(1);
       //call method from instance not as static
       System.Messaging.MessageQueue SomeQueue = myoj1.FunctionA();

       //I don't even know what this is supposed to do....
       //myoj1 .FunctionA(SomeQueue );
     }
   }
 }
```